# FTP account with access to /var/www (Debian)

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

I'm running Debian with ISPConfig3 and got multiple sites under main domain e.g. site1.domain.com (var/www/site1.domain.com), site2.domain.com (var/www/site2.domain.com), site3.domain.com (var/www/site3.domain.com)etc.
When I'm creating a new ftp account via ISPConfig panel I'm only able to asign one account per site. Is there any way I can create one ftp account with access to entire /var/www/ folder and all subdirectories?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using ISPConfig alone, that is not possible AFAIK, no.

You always have to be aware that a control panel can only do that much for you...

However you could create such an account manually on the system and set the home directory to whatever you like. But then, the created account certainly wouldn't have the permissions to go everywhere, and certainly not write.

So you really have to thing about what you really want first.